# Myhill-Nerode - Prove irregularity for $\{a^{n^3}\}$

Tags: regular-languages, formal-grammars

I need to prove that the following language is *not regular* by showing there are infinite pairwise  distinct equivalence classes:
$$
  L = \{a^{n^3} \mid n \geq 1\} \subseteq \{a\}^*
$$

Looking at a few examples, I intuitively noticed that for each $i \geq 1$ there is an equivalence class $[a^{i^3}] \neq [a^{j^3}]$ for $i \neq j$ because the number of  $a$'s we need to add increases exponentially with $i/j$. Thus for every $i$ we can add a suffix of $a$'s to reach the next higher power $(i+1)^3$ but the length of that suffix is different for every other power, so that each equivalence class only actually contains the representative itself.

**Example**:
$$
\begin{align*}
  &n = 1 \implies a \\
  &n = 2 \implies a^8 \\
  &n = 3 \implies a^{27} \\
  \vdots
\end{align*}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align*}
& [a] = \{x \in \{a\}^* \mid a \; R_L \; x\} = a \\
& [a^8] = \{x \in \{a\}^* \mid a^8 \; R_L \; x\} = a^8 \\
\vdots
\end{align*}
$$
Consider $[a]$. For $z = a^7$ we get $az = aa^7 = a^8 \in L$, but starting from $i \geq 2$, we have that $a^{i^3}z \notin L$.

How can I write this down in a more formal/rigorous way?

Comment: For $i\neq j$, let $k=\min(i,j)$. Then $z=a^{3k^2+3k+1}$ distinguishes $x=a^{i^3}$ and $y=a^{j^{3}}$. In fact, assume that $k=i$. Then $xz=a^{(i+1)^3}\in L$, while $yz=a^{j^3+3i^2+3i+1}\notin L$. The latter assertion is because $j^3<j^3+3i^2+3i+1<j^3+3j^2+3j+1=(j+1)^3$. Since $j^3+3i^2+3i+1$ is strictly between two consecutive cubes, it cannot itself be a cube.

Comment: Thanks @plop. Would have definitely given you a green mark :)

Answer (score 2):

More generally, you can use Myhill–Nerode to prove the following characterization:

> For $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, let $L(A) = \{ a^n : n \in A \}$.
>
> The language $L(A)$ is regular iff $A$ is eventually periodic.

In particular, if $A$ is an infinite set with *density zero* then $L(A)$ is not regular. Here *density zero* means:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|A \cap \{0,\ldots,n-1\}|}{n} = 0.
$$

This shows that $\{a^{n^k} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not regular for any $k \geq 2$.

---

Let us prove the claimed characterization. If $A$ is periodic, say with period $m$, then $L(A)$ is clearly regular: it is accepted by a circular DFA with $m$ states. If $A$ is eventually periodic then there is a periodic $B$ such that $L(A),L(B)$ differ in finitely many words, and so standard closure operations show that $L(A)$ is regular.

Now suppose that $L(A)$ is regular. The equivalent class of $a^m$ is the set $E_m = \{ k \in \mathbb{N} : m+k \in A \}$. Since there are finitely many equivalence classes, there exist $m < p$ such that $E_m = E_p$, that is, for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $m + k \in A$ iff $p + k \in A$. In other words, for all $\ell \geq m$, $\ell \in A$ iff $\ell + (p-m) \in A$. Hence $A$ is eventually periodic (with period $p-m$).